# Developing Angular v16 App into Remote VPS using VS Code SSH remote connection

Tags: angular, angular16

I am facing difficulties to develop my angular v16 using remote ssh in Visual Code, because my VPS is free to use i try to develop Angular into it. But when try to make build by typed "ng serve" and going into browser access localhost:4200 its not working, no display about Angular app in the browser just failed, only circle around in the icon bar.

I try enable port 4200 into firewall by typed sudo ufw allow 4200, that's still not working.

I am also try change the port into 5000 in my angular app, also give access firewall the 5000 port is not working too

please help T_T